# Import Error: No module name WEB & web_kanban

Tags: linux, eclipse, python-2.7, odoo

I am getting this error in odoo 7. I cloned it repository from git through eclipse. And when i try to run odoo configuration and visit localhost:8069 it shows "no handler found"

```
2018-03-09 10:04:37,543 14415 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0
2018-03-09 10:04:37,543 14415 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: /home/saif/odoo7/openerp/addons
2018-03-09 10:04:37,543 14415 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2018-03-09 10:04:37,544 14415 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2018-03-09 10:04:37,544 14415 INFO ? openerp: database user: saif
2018-03-09 10:04:37,603 14415 WARNING ? openerp.modules.module: module web: module not found
2018-03-09 10:04:37,676 14415 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web
2018-03-09 10:04:37,676 14415 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named web
2018-03-09 10:04:37,676 14415 ERROR ? openerp.service: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saif/odoo7/openerp/service/__init__.py", line 60, in load_server_wide_modules
openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/home/saif/odoo7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 405, in load_openerp_module
__import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/home/saif/odoo7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 132, in load_module
f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named web
2018-03-09 10:04:37,742 14415 WARNING ? openerp.modules.module: module web_kanban: module not found
2018-03-09 10:04:37,743 14415 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web_kanban
2018-03-09 10:04:37,743 14415 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named web_kanban
2018-03-09 10:04:37,743 14415 ERROR ? openerp.service: Failed to load server-wide module `web_kanban`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saif/odoo7/openerp/service/__init__.py", line 60, in load_server_wide_modules
openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/home/saif/odoo7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 405, in load_openerp_module
__import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/home/saif/odoo7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 132, in load_module
f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named web_kanban
2018-03-09 10:04:37,780 14415 INFO ? openerp.service.wsgi_server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2018-03-09 10:04:37,780 14415 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
```

Comment: Did you check that `web_kanban` module is inside an available directory? Look at the `addons_path` parameter of your Odoo configuration file.

Comment: Fixed. I created the config file through terminal. By going to odoo's folder like "cd odoo7" in the terminal and then tried this command 
   
python openerp-server --addons-path=" ./openerp/addons, ./addons"

And it worked. 
Also openerp-server is the default name of the config file. If this changed by someone or in some tutorial please make sure to change this name the configuration module as well.